# single column in dataframe needs to be broken up into 3 columns

Tags: pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup, multiple-columns

I have been using stack overflow a lot lately and I appreciate the community here.

I have a code that I have been working on that is finally starting to look like it should be I have one glitch that I haven't been able to get past.

I pulled data from a site for different states, they all have the same looking table with different data in it. I had to change the BeautifulSoup coding to make the loop work but now I have a pretty ugly column with all the data in it. It's easy to see which line goes where but don't really know how to get started in python.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
states = ["Washington", "Oregon"]

period = "2020"

num_states = len(states)

state_list = []

df = pd.DataFrame()
#df.columns['COUNTY','PAYMENT','TOTAL ACRES']

for state in states:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get('https://www.nbc.gov/pilt/counties.cfm')
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    state_s = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'state_code')
    drp = Select(state_s)
    drp.select_by_visible_text(state)
    year_s = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'fiscal_yr')
    drp = Select(year_s)
    drp.select_by_visible_text(period)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    link = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'Search')
    link.click()
    url = driver.current_url
    page = requests.get(url)
    #dfs  = pd.read_html(addrss)[2]
    # Get the html
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    table = soup.findAll('table')[2]
    headers = []

    for i in table.find_all('th'):
        title = i.text.strip()
        headers.append(title)
    


    for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
        data = row.find_all('td')
        row_data = [td.text.strip() for td in data]
        length = len(df)

df
```

output:

```
           0
0    ADAMS COUNTY
1         $59,408
2          21,337
0   ASOTIN COUNTY
1        $174,550
..            ...
1         $38,627
2          58,311
0           TOTAL
1     $23,321,995
2      31,312,205

[228 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: I don't see where you add data to the dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set a custom index then use `unstack()` and rename. This is based on the assumption that the headers in your pic above match your target dataset, (i.e the index is repeated in multiples of 3)

```
df1 = df.set_index(df.groupby(level=0)\
                   .cumcount(),append=True).stack()\
                   .unstack(0)\
                   .rename(columns={0 : 'County', 1: 'Price', 2 : 'Population?'})


print(df1)

                County            Price      Population?
0 1       ADAMS COUNTY          $59,408           21,337
1 1      ASOTIN COUNTY         $174,550           58,311
2 1     ANOTHER COUNTY          $38,627       31,312,205
3 1              TOTAL      $23,321,995              NaN
```

Comment: Awesome thanks a ton! That worked perfectly...really quickly do you know how I could assign the state on to the end as an additional column?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with US geography, but I assume a county resides within a state? if so you just need to do a merge or use `.map` where is `State` at the moment? @BenSorensen

Comment: sure, yes counties do lie within states, at the top of my code you will see that I have a list of states and selenium loops through those states to generate the list that we have here. What I am wondering is if we can just put the name of the state that I had selenium working with as the last value of the table?

Comment: unfortunately i don't have Selenium installed or the web driver downloaded - so I can't test. Personally, instead of lists I would build up your data using a dictionary so you know what comes from where. @BenSorensen